# STEP Motor Maximum Speed

Tags: arduino, pic, motor-controller, stepper-motor, firmware

Hello I'm struggling with getting my nema 23 step motor(3A max) to achieve maximum speeds and I'm wondering if its the algorithm or the motor driver. I'm using 24 volt power supply with TB6600 step motor driver(I'm using 1/16 micro stepping with current limited to 3 amps). Now I'm getting the motor to accelerate and decelerate properly using a trapezoidal movement profile using period look up table. The motor moves good and accelerates properly, however I know it should be able to move faster. I'm programing using PIC microcontroller and I'm wondering if the algorithm or the clock speed is the limiting factor for the top speed of the motor. The algorithm is briefly explained below.

```
    while(true)
      {
                                                                          
       if(step!=dest) {
                                                                                
               //enable motor                                                                        
               if(motor_counter ==0){
               step ++ ;//increment step counter 
               period = LUT[step]; //set period based of position acceleration lookup
                motor_counter = period ;                                                                    
                step_pin(High);   // toggle the step pin  
                } 
                else {
                step_pin(low) // dont step 
                motor_counter -- ;
                 }                                                     
     }
     else {                                                                                              
      disablemotor 
     }
```

the actual code is a little more complex but this is just a generalization of the stepping algorithm. The algorithm is simple as the position increases the period will reach one. however I'm noticing that even at the smallest period the speed still isn't fast as it should be able to go. I'm thinking that maybe the clock speed of the microcontroller is what is limiting the speed here. Let me know if you can see the issue here. I also tried to use the accelstepper library but the speeds were not as fast as my own code. Any suggestions or insight would help. I don't think the motor looses steps anyway because the position control seems accurate and repeatable.

Comment: What is the required step frequency calculated from target speed?

Comment: the step pin  frequency measured when the motor_period was minimum value=1 was 32kHz

Comment: OK, but which frequency do you need?

Comment: I'm not sure on the maximum frequency that I need. I would like to move the motor as fast as possible. Not using PWM pins of the microcontroller and making the algorithm above which is pwm like the fastest frequency I was able to generate was 32khz.

Comment: What is your stepper motor?

Comment: Nema 23 step  motor rated for 24DC and 2.6 amps

Comment: How many steps for the motor?